# Laptop not turning on,led blinks on and off

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have dell inspiron 3542. Yesterday while my laptop was plugged in with the charger it suddenly went off.
Then when I tried to turn it on the led light at the rear goes on, stays for 2 seconds and then again goes off and this process repeats and display not showing anything. 
When I put my ear near the TouchPad something tries to spin but can't and repeats this.
Can anyone help me out please

Comment: Remove the battery and try it with only the power adapter, any changes?

Answer (score -2):

Frequently, when this happens, the computer is completely unable to even emit an audible error code (a beep).  It can be related to processor overheating (your CPU is fried) but generally it is not.  For the most part, you'll probably find a layer of oxidation has formed on the memory DIMMs or on the DIMM sockets.

This presumes the computer is in "first-failure" mode, meaning you haven't already taken the computer apart and possibly inflicted some additional damage to it, in which case you may have a multiplicity of problems, all of which need to be resolved before the computer will become operational again.

Sometimes you'll find computer technicians report having simply "reseated" the DIMMs (they took the DIMMs out and put them back in again) which sounds kind of useless, especially considering what they've charged you.  What they're doing, wittingly or not, is removing that layer of oxidation so the DIMMs can make good contact with the DIMM socket.

(If you're about to race over to the computer and try this without reading the rest, at least note which DIMM came out of which slot, ground yourself and the computer and remove all power, including the battery.)

Some people remove the DIMMs and use the eraser of a normal pencil to erase away the oxidation layer from both sides of each DIMM and the from the connectors.

Good and bad.

If you remove the DIMMs and your body is not at the same ground level as the computer, you could fry the DIMMs and / or other computer components with a discharge of electricity from an otherwise static charge, in which case they'll likely never work again.  Using a static grounding strap for both the computer and the person working on the computer (grounded to the same ground) will likely prevent static zapping the computer and / or the DIMMs.  If you can't find it within yourself to run down to the electronics store and buy a grounding kit, at least hold on to the metallic frame of the computer while you're performing this operation.

This operation will likely void any warranty you had, as manufacturers generally deem there is a likelihood of getting eraser filings in the computer, specifically in the DIMM slots, which can prevent a proper connection.

If you can SAFELY (unplug the computer first and remove the battery) remove the DIMMs, clean the connectors (not over the computer) and re-insert them into alternate DIMM slots, you may be able to recover the computer.  (If there are two DIMM slots, first try reinserting the DIMMs -- after cleaning -- into the alternate slot.  If that doesn't work, return the DIMMs to their original slots.)

There are a lot of things which can completely disable a computer's ability to even emit a beep code but this one is the most common.

Good luck!

Comment: There can be several other reasons too. Also not all computers use audio error codes.